# Dockerfile passing wrong mysql host ip address

Tags: mysql, docker, automation, dockerfile, magento2

> I created a build on my local machine and was working great. Now
>   trying to do same in the server.It is not passing the host-ip set in
>   Dockerfile but passing **172.17.0.3** and throwing the bellow error

**Here is the error:**

```
Step 22/25 : RUN cd /usr/html/bin  &&      ./magento setup:config:set --db-host=172.17.0.2 --db-name=mydb --db-user=tara --db-password=password
 ---> Running in 7bbe53f5d054
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'tara'@'172.17.0.3' (using password: YES)

  [InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed
```

***Where the host ip comes from the IP address of another running container. which is 172.17.0.2 ***

Why is it taking wrong IP address during connection

**HERE is the dockerfile:**

```
FROM docker-php:0.2
#mysqql setup
ENV DB_HOST 172.17.0.2
ENV DB_NAME mydb
ENV DB_USER admin
ENV DB_PASSWORD password

#magenot admin user
ENV ADMIN_USER tara
ENV ADMIN_PASSWORD password123
ENV ADMIN_FIRSTNAME tara
ENV ADMIN_LASTNAME gurung
ENV ADMIN_EMAIL tara.email@somelink.net


ADD ./magento2 /usr/html/

WORKDIR /usr/html/

RUN find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
RUN find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
RUN chown -R :docker .
RUN chmod u+x bin/magento

RUN composer install
CMD echo "Success installed Magento"

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/docker/run.sh"]
#get into the magento isntallation dir
#get into the magento isntallation dir
#start setting the necessasry file permission first
RUN cd /usr/html && \
    chmod 777 generated -R && \
    chmod 777 var -R

RUN cd /usr && \
    chown -R docker:docker html     

#start running the magento commands to install
RUN cd /usr/html/bin  && \
     ./magento setup:config:set  --db-host=$DB_HOST --db-name=mydb --db-user=bhavi --db-password=password
#installing the magento with admin user created
RUN cd /usr/html/bin && \
    ./magento setup:install --admin-user=$ADMIN_USER --admin-password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD --admin-firstname=$ADMIN_FIRSTNAME --admin-lastname=$ADMIN_LASTNAME --admin-email=ADMIN_EMAIL --use-rewrites=1


RUN chmod 777 vendor -R
RUN cd /usr && \
    chown -R docker:docker html
```

Comment: Check the output of `docker inspect --format '{{ json ($.Config) }}' 888d12ebb5b3 | python -m json.tool` for `Cmd` and `Env`. Looks like you're spinning up containers off an older image. You may need to rebuild a new image off your Dockerfile

Comment: 172.17.0.3 is likely the address of the intermediary container that docker-build creates to handle that RUN step. (1) You shouldn't make any assumptions wrt the addresses of containers attached to Docker bridge networks (which I assume is the case as the 172.17.0.0 network is the first one used by default by the Docker engine). Use the embedded Docker DNS server instead (reference container names or aliases, not IP addresses). (2) Don't set up a service (db) with the build procedure of an image. Images are intended to be deployable and directly usable across hosts.

Comment: For now I created a users in mysql that accepts any hosts IP using this mysql commands `CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`